# Jquery Webapplications

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I read now a few days here and i learn a lot of things.

Now i want to ask you, if you know web based applications, which uses jQuery. At the Moment i have only one example: http://gantter.com/

My special interests are webapplications not websites. I know the technologies are the same - but the view is totally diffrent.

I hope to start a intresting Linklist with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Agilezen.com](http://agilezen.com) is a beautifully written web app that uses jQuery.

It's sort of a User-story story board...

Comment: Yes I search for applications like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery ? :D

Edit: Sorry, should've read the last part. Anyway, there are some apps on the site, mostly sites though.

Edit2: It is a wiki, so instead of making a linklist here, I'd suggest adding some links there.

Answer (score 1):

:) [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) uses jQuery as well.
It's really **very** popular library, and you'll have lot of fun with it.
Very easy to learn, very easy to use, very easy to extend.
Huge community, huge plugin repository!
I used recently in one intranet application.
I was really afraid of using yet another library for my app. But it turned to be the most right decision I've made for this app!

Comment: :) yes. Stackoverflow rules. an use jQuery but is not really this what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is one great [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/10083) for Firefox which let's you see which library is used on the website.

Just install it and browse the internet. You'll be amazed how many websites use jQuery or any other JS framework.
Good Luck!